# :before pseudoelement not showing up

Tags: html, css

I can't get the `:before` pseudoelement to display. I want to create a shape behind the `<h2>` element in question.

http://jsfiddle.net/cbeLanvb/2/

```
<div id="container">
<h2 id="info_text_startday_explain">turmas começam</h2>
<h1 id="info_text_startday">10 de Maio</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
height: auto;
width: 300px;
background-color: red;
}

#info_text_startday_explain{
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 2em;
color: black;
}
#info_text_startday{
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
color: white;
font-size: 2.8em;
}

#info_text_starday:before{
position: absolute;
content: '';
z-index: 2;
background-color: black;
border: 3px solid white;
height: 300px;
width: 290px;   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have a typo in your CSS**..

The `id` for the `div` is `info_text_startday` and in your css you have `#info_text_starday:before`

so replace in your css as

```
#info_text_startday:before{
position: absolute;
content: '';
z-index: 2;
background-color: black;
border: 3px solid white;
height: 300px;
width: 290px;   
}
```

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/cbeLanvb/3/)

Comment: thanks, that worked. what a dumb mistake.

Now the pseudo element is being displayed on my actual page, but it's not respecting z-index!

Comment: That might be due to the different positioning that you have used..absolute for one and relative for another.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/cbeLanvb/5/) what you want? give a negative value for `z-index`

Comment: that worked! So :before the z-index of :before pseudoelements use their reference element as the z-index context.  I appreciate your help!